# Blender doesn't use gpu GTX 1060 max Q

Tags: rendering

So my laptop has a GTX 1060 6GB Max Q, i put the render setting in blender to the gtx 1060 max Q. But when rendering, it doesn't use a bit of that gpu, and it doesn't use any of the intergrated. I checked my Nvidia control panel and it shows that Blender uses the GTX 1060 Max Q. I already updated my gpu driver to the lasted. 
It takes forever for my laptop to render with my cpu. I really need help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you put your graphic card in your blender’s settings ?
Putting it in your render settings won’t make it use the graphic card unless you’ve specified the card in blender settings :

[image: Sorry for the quality]

In system tab, change the computing device to CUDA and select your graphic card.
Don’t forget to save the settings :)

Comment: Yes I did, and I did click save, but still